# Running both Node.js and Apache on the same domain and "URL"

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, ports

Is it possible to run Both node and Apache on the same domain without adding the port in the URL ?
and serve both on the same page, i already have node running on port 8443 and Apache on port 433 and they both work fine but i need to specify in the link the port "8443" to access node which is not what i want,
i want to serve both on the same URL if possible without adding the port to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

Add this configuration to your apache conf.

`ProxyPass "/nodeapp"  "http:/localhost:8443"`

You can access node application by `http://www.example.com/nodeapp`

A reverse proxy is a type of proxy server that retrieves resources on behalf of a client from server. These resources are then returned to the client as if they originated from the web server itself.

Comment: Never mind i realized that what i'm asking for is stupid because that would be sending all Apache requests to node instead i will just go with this solution you provided thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an nginx proxy before them and separate routes to apache or node.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/